# Query executa FilterRecord apenas uma vez

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho uma consulta em tQuery que tem a necessidade de fazer FilterRecord. 
Após exibir os dados faço uma busca interna na consulta por item mais específico, como por exemplo o nome, porém quando faço a busca na query ela prontamente executa a busca corretamente, quando vou retirando letras não passa pelo FilterRecord novamnte, mesmo utilizando o Query.Refresh.

Alguém sabe como faço para que o TQuery execute novamente o FilterRecord ?

Comment: O FilterRecord só é executado quando existe algo na propriedade `Filter` e um registro diferente se torna ativo. Se você precisa refazer a leitura dos registros, altere o SQL do TQuery.

Comment: Então é necessário colocar um filtro. E se o filtro já esteja na query, porém preciso no momento da exibição na grid, no caso uma busca dentro do que está listado na GridView, como por exemplo o nome. Assim não é necessário fazer OPEN e CLOSE na query todas as vezes.

Comment: O TQuery não foi feito para esse tipo de comportamento. Se você quer filtrar o conteúdo que já foi buscado e mostrado no DataSet, você vai ter que utilizar outro componente que permita esse tipo de manipulação, como o TClientDataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom @LuizVichiatto, como havia prometido 
no comentário da reposta anterior fiz um exemplo
que funciona perfeitamente.

Passo 1: coloque no Form um DataSource, DbGrid, Edit e um DataSet no meu caso usei o ClientDataSet, mas pode ser qualquer outro que suporte a propriedade Filter.

Passo 2: configure os eventos conforme abaixo

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, DB, DBClient, Grids, DBGrids;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    cdsBusca: TClientDataSet;
    EditBusca: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
    cdsBuscaNome: TStringField;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure EditBuscaChange(Sender: TObject);
    procedure cdsBuscaFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet; var Accept: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: integer;
begin
  cdsBusca.CreateDataSet;
  cdsBusca.Append;
  cdsBuscaNome.Value := 'Monica';
  cdsBusca.Append;
  cdsBuscaNome.Value := 'Eduardo';
  cdsBusca.Append;
  cdsBuscaNome.Value := 'Renato Russo';
  cdsBusca.Post;
end;

procedure TForm1.EditBuscaChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cdsBusca.Filtered := False;
  cdsBusca.Filter := '';
  cdsBusca.Filtered := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.cdsBuscaFilterRecord(DataSet: TDataSet;
  var Accept: Boolean);
begin
   if EditBusca.Text = '' then
   begin
      cdsBusca.Filtered := False;
      Exit;
   end;
   Accept := Pos(EditBusca.Text, cdsBuscaNome.AsString) > 0;
end;

end.
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui adicionei o nome Edmilson, apenas para filtrar tudo que continha a letra
"E"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Wellington.
Agradeço, vou fazer os testes e te informo do resultado.
att
Luiz!

Comment: Beleza, funciona como indicado. Obrigado pela dica.
Somente ficou um problema, uma dll tal de Midas que não está atualizando, acredito que é outra questão.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, como foi dito nos comentários supracitados, para chamar o evento FilterRecords deve ser adicionada
alguma condição na propriedade filter do DataSet exemplo:

```
TQuery.Filtered := False;
TQuery.Filter := //Condição;
TQuery.Filtered := True;
```

Sobre a questão de digitar uma letra e filtrar 
você poderia colocar a seguinte condição no 
evento FilterRecords, forçando o filter é claro:

```
procedure TForm1.TQueryFilterRecord(Dataset: TDataset; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := Pos(EditBusca.Text, DataSet.FieldByName(NomeItem).AsString) > 0;
end;
```

Uma solução mais fácil e recomendada é verificar 
se o operador Like é suportado para o banco de dados
que vc está usando se for, poderá fazer o seguinte:

```
TQuery.Filter := 'NomeCampo LIKE '+ quotedStr('%') +
EditBusca.Text + quotedStr('%');
TQuery.Filtered := True;
```

Referência: [Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Data.DB.TDataSet.Filter)

Comment: Não tem paragrafos, os 4 espaços são sempre para definir um bloco de código.

Comment: Isso já está sendo feito, o problema é que executo a query, ele processa o FilterRecord, quando preencho um edit.text, mas se altero o edit.text ele não volta a executar o FilterRecord

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, já tentou utilizar seu código no evento OnChange desse edit.text? Digo forçar a passagem no FiltterRecord quando você mudar o que está no edit.

Comment: ola Wellington, sim e o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, mais tarde te mando um exemplo funcionando, porque agora estou no trabalho

Comment: @LuizVichiatto, já coloquei o exemplo em outra resposta, foi malz a demora estava muito ocupado, vlw